# How to write a app to connect an Android device to a host USB GPS device

Tags: android, usb

I have a standalone GPS enabled data recorder in my car that can function as either a USB host or device. (Its a class 0x00h USB device). I currently connect to it via a WM 6.5 app running on my Palm Treo 750.

I would like to port my WM 6.5 app to an Android phone.  (I don't have a specific Android phone in mind, I would like it to be as generic as possible).

Replicating the GUI is not that difficult, but I am having trouble getting started on the USB communication.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me towards an example, or the appropriate tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, none of the android devices support Host Mode without a "hack" to enable it so you would be limited on the devices that could use it. So the USB communication info is probably limited. 

Every android device ive seen has GPS built in, couldn't you just use the built in GPS device and process the data?

Comment: Apps like trackmaster can use an external GPS so it is possible to use a USB GPS Device, but I havent done it.

Comment: They are probably using the external gps via bluetooth, not usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably cannot do this without modifying the android installation on the phone or modifying the GPS.

Three methods come to mind:

a) modify the GPS so that in host mode it can talk the android ADB protocol and do something like driver the adb shell or simulate an adb port forward to talk to the appliction on the phone

b) modify the android installation to support an additional usb target capability already supported by the gps, such as emulating a usb-serial converter or emultaing your wm phone.

c) modify the android installation to function as a usb host, and compile in a usb driver for the gps previously tested on a desktop linux

a requires in depth development for the gps, b & c require rooting the phone

oh, one more:

d) Get a usb-target microcontroller board with bluetooth.  Plug into the GPS and implement a target interface that the GPS host can talk to.  Use serial over bluetooth to talk to the phone.

Comment: My assumption is the GPS device would act as the host, and my Android phone would be the device.

Comment: Fine - but you need to do either a) and give the GPS a driver for the android phone's existing USB client mode, or do b) and give the android phone a new usb client mode compatible with a driver the GPS already has.

Comment: I am wondering if I can make use of the USB mass storage class.  My understanding is that most Android phones support the mass storage class, and can be used as portable flash drivers.  My GPS host also supports the mass storage class.  Can I have my GPS host and the android phone both writing files to the flash storage card on the phone while the USB cable is connected, and pass messages that way?

Comment: No.  During the time when the android device has its sdcard mounted to an external USB host, it's not accessible from onboard the phone.  You'd have to make major changes to the USB mass storage driver on the phone to change that, which would require rooting and it would still be ugly.  If you are going to root the android phone to modify its usb drivers, implement whatever the GPS was using to talk to the wm phone.

Comment: Is there a way to enable/disable sharing the sd card from within an Android App?  Through the UI I can switch between 'Charge Only', and 'Disk Drive'.  I have not been able to find a method to change this from within a program.

Comment: It should not be possible for an application to do that, as it's a "user talks directly to android"-level security concern.  Of course if you trash the security model by rooting the phone, you can eventually figure out how to manipulate vold to accomplish that.  But it's still not a good way to communicate as the turnaround time is outrageous.